# How to setup cookie-based stickiness on NGINX Open source for socket.io?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nginx, socket.io

I'm currently getting random sudden 400 errors (Session ID unknown) when trying to use multiple nodes for an application using socket.io. I believe this has to do with issues with the stickiness.

I use NGINX, and have enabled stickiness using the `ip_hash`, as suggested on the documentation: https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes#nginx-configuration

This, works but, I am unable to use this same approach in production. So I am looking at using the cookie that can be set with socket.io: https://socket.io/how-to/deal-with-cookies#cookie-based-sticky-session

With this approach, the amount of 400 - Session ID unknown errors I get are less, but it's still failing (something I don't see using `ip_hash`).

I am aware there is a paid approach for stickiness based on cookies for NGINX Plus, but I wonder if this is possible with the Open Source version.

I have tried the following:

1. Enable the cookie and balance the load based on it:

In the server side:

```
  const socketsServer = createServer(server);
  
  const options = {
    origin: (_req, callback) => {
      callback(null, true);
    },
    credentials: true,
    pingInterval: 3000,
    serveClient: false,
    cookie: true,
    adapter: createAdapter(redis.getClient())
  }
  
  const io = new Server(socketsServer, options)
```

In NGINX

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://nodes;

      # enable WebSockets
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }

  upstream nodes {
  # also tried hash $cookie_io consistent;
    hash $cookie_io 
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
  }
}
```

2. Use custom headers.

In the client.

```
this.socket = io({HOST}, {
    reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
    withCredentials: true,
    extraHeaders: {
        mid: mid // A random consistent value
    }
});
```

In NGINX.

```
http {
  server {
   ...
  }

  upstream nodes {
   # also tried hash $http_mid consistent;
    hash $http_mid
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
  }
}
```

Both these approaches lead to less 400 errors (Session ID unknown), but I still see some. Which leads me to believe this is not actually applying any stickiness.